# Is it possible to change email address of a Google group via API?

Tags: gdata-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client, google-provisioning-api

I am trying to find a way to rename (change email address aka group id) a google group via api.  Using the python client libraries and the provisioning api i am able to modify the group name and description, and I have used the group settings api to modify a group's settings.  Is there a way to change the email address?

Answer (score 1):

There is no group rename function for groups as there is for users. With the Group Settings and Provisioning APIs though, you can capture much of the group specifics and migrate that over to a new group. You would lose:

-Group Archive

-Managers (show only as members)

-Email Delivery (Immediate, Digest, No-Delivery, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jay.  I think I'll end up editing the email addresses manually via the old Groups control panel.